# how to display anchor tag on condition and when clicked on anchor show content else not (new to angular)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have made anchor tag to display on condition using ng-show.How will i deal with clicking on anchor and display content

```
 <span><a class = "req-clickable" ng-show = "vm.inScopeServicesListLength >= 6">+{{vm.moreInscopeServices}}more</a> 
                <span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on more

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

<span><a class= "req-clickable" ng-click="vm.increase()" ><span  ng-show = "vm.inScopeServicesListLength >= 1">+{{vm.moreInscopeServices}} </span>more</a><span>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.inScopeServicesListLength = 0;
    vm.moreInscopeServices = 'NEW' ;
    vm.increase = function(){
     vm.inScopeServicesListLength++;
    };

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ......but 'more' should not display again after i display 'NEW'